# Can the variability of this multi-variate categorical data set be computed?

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, variability

I have a set of Survey responses in the format shown below. I want to provide a mathematical measure of Variability to show "how different" the population is, but I'm not sure how to do so without doing 16! comparisons. Is there a way to compute any sort of Measure of Variability with Categorical Data like this using either excel or R?
[image: Excel Example]

Comment: "Different" by itself is meaningless: **to what** do you wish to compare these data?  What do you mean by "population"?  What do the columns represent?

Comment: Each group represents an individual and each question represents a question asked to or about the individual. I'm looking for a mathematical measure, possibly of variability, to effectively determine a level of homogeneity. Part of the difficulty I am having is due to the lack of a "target" to compare each individual to.